# querySelectorAll doesnt do anything

Tags: javascript

Why i cant get this extremly simple script to work. It works with querySelector, but not with querySelectorAll

HTML

```
<p id="log2"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dom.js"></script>
```

JS

```
var q = document.querySelectorAll("#log2").innerHTML+="<p>qwerty</p>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (which is like an array), not a single HTMLElement.

You need to either grab the first element from it (`[0]`) or loop over it.

There is no point in using `All` with an ID selector since IDs must be unique.

```
<p class="log2"></p>
<p class="log2"></p>
<p class="log2"></p>

<script>
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".log2");
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].innerHTML+="<p>qwerty</p>";
};
</script>
```

Comment: Yes i know that it shouldnt be used like that, it was just for the purpose of demonstration, anyway thank You very much my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of elements (i.e. multiple elements).

To pick up the first element use either `document.querySelectorAll("#log2")[0]`, or `document.querySelector("#log2")`.

In your case you are trying to get an element by ID, which should be only one element on the page. Hence, you may use cross browser method `document.getElementById("log2")` instead.